# Moving data from Oracle12C to SQL 2022

Tags: sql-server, oracle-12c, sql-server-2022

Currently we have to migrate off of our SQL 2012 server since it is outside Microsoft support. We currently have replication from an Oracle 12C database to current SQL 2012. We like to move to 2022 but it seems like Oracle 12C replication to SQL 2022 is not supported. I need to sync 250 tables from Oracle to SQL is there a way to do this that does not include SSIS because SSIS would require a package for each table in order to move the data. Is there any other solution that may help us get this task done.

Comment: What is your current replication solution?

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, you're trying to move from SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server 2022 but currently are trying to do so with a middleman of an Oracle SQL server? If so, why not just restore a backup from 2012 directly to 2022 instead (cut out the middleman)?

Comment: Currently there is replication from the Oracle 12C to MSSQL  2012 replication to this version is supported not MSSQL 2022. There are also SSIS packages that move data at a daily interval. So my comes is how can we move the data most effectively on a continuous basis. This data being pulled to a data warehouse.

Answer (score -1):

When you update Sql-Server because it's out of support, couldn't you update Oracle as well?

Comment: Hi, this is not an answer. Please delete it and ask your question in the comments of the original Post instead.

Comment: We do not control or administer the source Database so updating it is out om my teams control we manage SQL only and help in the pulling of data into the teams data warehouse